# Print attachment without opening

Tags: outlook-2010

I have a user that want to be able to print multiple emails and the tiff attachments without opening the attachments (or the emails).   I have been doing a lot of googling, but I haven't found anything that doesn't require the attachment to be opened first.

Anyone have an idea?

thanks

Comment: You can also use an automatic tool which connect directly to your email box like automatic email manager: http://www.automatic-email-manager.com

Answer (score 0):

If you select all the e-mails you want to print press ctrl+p and then click 'Print Options' and make sure 'Print Attached Files' is checked.

Comment: but that will still require the files to be opened in a tiff viewer.  I need the attachment not to open at all.